# Add hyperlink to custom web part properties

Tags: development, custom, properties

I would like to add a hyperlink to a custom web part which will take the users to a web page on a new window with the configuration settings for the web part. If I try and add a text property as below, it will have a textbox associated with it.

```
[WebBrowsable(true),
Category("News Options"),
Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.Shared),
WebDisplayName("Click the link below to view configuration settings")]
public string WebPartSettingsPage
{
  get;
  set;
}
```

Is there a way to add something similar to a label control that would just display a link the users can can click?

Answer (score 3):

The only option is to create a custom editor part. Check out [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228018.aspx) msdn example.

Answer (score 0):

Calling the MSOTlPn_ShowToolPane2Wrapper javascript function will open the web part in edit mode.  Add this line to CreateChildControls():

```
this.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(string.Format(@"<BR>This Web Part has not been configured. <A href=""javascript:MSOTlPn_ShowToolPane2Wrapper('Edit',this,'{0}')"">Open the tool pane</A> to configure properties.<BR><BR>", this.ID)));
```